# Почему из формы передается null

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Помогите разобраться, почему при передачи из Jquery post метода на контрольку теряются данные

```
$("#submit").click(function () {
    var url = "/"
    var resault_array = [];
    $('input').each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr('type') == 'textarea') {
            resault_array.push($(this).val());
        }

    });
    console.log(resault_array);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/home/Parse',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(resault_array),
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.success) {
                alert(data);
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }});

});
```

т.е. при нажатии кнопки скрипт собирается данные, которые заполнил пользователь и должен их передать на контроллер в метод Parse 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data: { urls : resault_array },
```